# Change NODATA pixel value in raster to arbitrary value

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-2.6, nodata

I want to change the value in all pixels that are currently 0 to 800 in QGIS 2.6.1. 0 is listed as the no-data value in Properties > Transparency. I have unchecked the No Data Value box there. Then I have tried the following.

1) Set Settings > Option > Data Sources > Representation for NULL Values = 800. Save as... to make a new .tif raster layer, WITH and WITHOUT specifying a range for No Data Values in the Save As... dialog. I thought that maybe a range from -1 to 1 would handle real-representation zeroes better. Either way, the raster returned is just like the original, with no change to the no-data (value=0) pixels.

2) Processing Toolbox > Geoalgorithms > Raster > General Tools > Raster Calculator, with expression: `ifelse(lt(a,1), (800)`, a). Still no dice, the no-data value is now `-99999`.

3) Raster menu > Raster Calculator, with expression: `("my layer here@1" >= 0) * "my layer here@1"`. Interestingly, now the no-data value is `-3.40282...E+38`.

4) Processing Toolbox > Geoalgorithms > Raster > Edition > Reclassify Grid Values. This tool didn't work at all. Tried [0] Single, [1] Range, and [2] Simple Table options, with and without saving to a file. Log gave a bunch of errors about being unable to load modules. The path to the .dlls is correct.

5) Processing Toolbox > Geoalgorithms > Raster > Edition > Reclassify (Simple), with range option -1 to 1. Returned a raster with the no-data value = -99999.

For the record, all tests were done with the Null Representation = 800, but I also tried several of the methods with the default representation of NULL. Results were the same. I have also exported the raster as XYZ format and looked at it in CloudCompare; the null values are being expressed as the value reported in Properties > Transparency.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **r.null.to** function via GRASS to transform all NULL value cells into a user-defined value, which in your case is 800:

[image: r.null.to]

Note: You will have to create a GRASS Mapset before you can use **r.null.to** as it is not available in the *Processing Toolbox*. Once you created a mapset, use the GRASS option to add a raster layer, select *Open GRASS Tools* and search the Module list:

[image: GRASS Tools]

[image: Module list]