# QGIS Raster Calculator, joining two raster

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

In QGIS raster calculator I do:

[image]

Plus (+)

[image]

And I get:

[image]

The red circle in the middle is like cut in the result, QGIS it's not adding every pixel on each raster, it makes a kind of intersecction...

If i select in the QGIS layer selector the two layers to be added (using blending effects = multiply) i get visually pretty much what I spected to see when making the raster calculation adding:

[image]

How could I make a real adding calculation between two rasters?

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace your Nodata values with 0 and repeat your calculation. To do that you could try: [Change NODATA pixel value in raster to arbitrary value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126851/change-no-data-pixel-value-in-raster-qgis-2-6).

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull also with the outter box of your raters. I think it's also that the outter box of the raster1 is smaller then the raster2. So you need to extend the box of the raster1 to be the same as raster2.
Otherwise it can't do raster1 + raster2, where raster1 doesn't exist!